# How to create a view controller that supports both landscape and portrait, but does not rotate between them (keeps its initial orientation)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a view controller that supports both landscape and portrait orientations, but that *can not* rotate between them - that is, the view should retain its original orientation.

I have tried creating an ivar `initialOrientation` and setting it in `-viewDidAppear` with

```
initialOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
```

then

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == initialOrientation);
}
```

But that causes confusing problems (presumably because `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is called before `-viewDidAppear`).

How can I lock the orientation to its original orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on the right track, I guess. I solved this by making `initialOrientation` a property, then setting it from the calling viewController:

```
OrientationLockedViewController *vc = [[OrientationLockedViewController alloc] init];
vc.initialOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
```

Now I have, in `OrientationLockedViewController`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == self.initialOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of a weird requirement and not something I think UIKit was designed to handle. I don't think its documented when UIKit will call `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` or how long it might cache those results so I see two possibilities if this behavior is important.

1. Set the `initialOrientiation` early, when you init your view controller if not earlier so your `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` behavior never changes but the app will respect the orientation it started in.
2. Detect the device orientation before you display this controller's view and apply your view's rotation transformation yourself. Depending on your view controller hierarchy you might need to advertise support for all rotations to allow the device to rotate and then set a transform on your view to always rotate to the same orientation regardless of the device's orientation.

Comment: Looks like I'm slow and you went for option #1. That should hopefully work reliably for you as long as you don't need this controller instance to be able to switch its `initialOrientation` when it is not visible.

Comment: A good point. Naming the property `initialOrientation` should make it clear that changing this value (even if the view is off screen) is not supported.